# Why does `sched_setscheduler()` require root priveledges?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, root

Why does `sched_setscheduler()` require root priveledges?

I am writing some code that benefits from setting SCHED_FIFO. But if I use sched_setscheduler() I now must require this process to be run as root. Why not allow `sched_setscheduler()` to be run without root permissions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably because processes using a realtime scheduler can completely take over a machine and not give the CPU to other processes - which normal users should not have the power to do.

Linux allows you to do a bit more fine grained control than running as root though, you can set the CAP_SYS_NICE [capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) on your executable (done once, as the root user) with the command:

```
 setcap cap_sys_nice+ep ./your_program
```

Which will allow your executable to use sched_setscheduler even when it's not run as the root user.

Comment: note: running `setcap` as you described requires root (at least on my machine. maybe add sudo to your command.

Comment: Forcing my program to run as root would IMO be like giving access to everything when the process really only needs special access for one specific thing. So this solution seems optimal in-the-sense-of-security solution because it gives the minimal elevated security permissions for ONLY what is needed instead of everything (i.e. forcing to run as root).

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Another commonly used approach is to run the program as [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) root, which makes the process run as the root user regardless of the user that starts it, and have the program programatically drop privileges after any root only features are executed (after the sched_setscheduler() call in your case).

Comment: The [setcap](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap) man page points you to [cap_from_text](http://linux.die.net/man/3/cap_from_text) man page, it means to add the (the **+**) the **e**ffective and the **p**ermitted cap_sys_nice capability. The meaning of effective and permitted are stated in the [capabilites](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) man page

Answer (score 2):

Because it allows your process to change how much CPU other processes get, which can be abused.

Comment: If I understand correctly, essentially requiring root is a design decision tradeoff. The choice to require root was made because the pros outweighed the cons.